# Strange AttributeError in Flask based website

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask

I am developing a website based on Flask and SQLAlchemy

1. `ss`is created by sessionmaker in sqlalchemy.orm
2. Anime, ActorQuote, AnimeComment are models based on database structure

```

```
@app.route('/page/<anime_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_page(anime_name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        anime = ss.query(Anime).filter_by(anime_name=anime_name).first()
        actor_quotes = ss.query(ActorQuote).filter_by(anime_id=anime.id).all()
        anime_comments = ss.query(AnimeComment).filter_by(anime_id=anime.id).all()
        return render_template('page.html', anime=anime, actor_lines=actor_quotes, comments=anime_comments)
```

As excepted, it would return a page with these arguments -- anime, actor_quotes, anime_comments, and it does, but also throw a Attribute Error.

```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/windrunner/hiacg/index.py", line 138, in show_page
    actor_lines = ss.query(ActorQuote).filter_by(anime_id=anime.id).all()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

When I use try-except to catch the error, it throws another UnboundLocalError.

```

```
try:
    anime = ss.query(Anime).filter_by(anime_name=anime_name).first()
    actor_quotes = ss.query(ActorQuote).filter_by(anime_id=anime.id).all()
    anime_comments = ss.query(AnimeComment).filter_by(anime_id=anime.id).all()
except AttibuteError:
    print 'AttibuteError occurs again!'
```

What is more strange is the website still works well as nothing happened.

1. [/page/化物语](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTzY.png) This shows the page as expected without error.
2. [/page/剑风传奇](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTzY.png) This shows the page as expected but with error.

Comment: Can you show the code inside your except block?

Comment: @alKid I've add try-except clause and also Tracebck msg.

Answer (score 3):

In your line

```
anime = ss.query(Anime).filter_by(anime_name=anime_name).first()
```

the variable `anime` is `None` if not found (as you said in database empty) and thus the `AttributeError` when trying to access `None`.`id`.

Btw I kindly suggest you to use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) extension that tackles all the db connection logic and exposes some useful functions such as `.first_or_404'.
With it your code would become

```
anime = Anime.query.filter_by(anime_name=anime_name).first_or_404()
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, I mean the actor_quotes table is empty, not the whole db. And I can confirm it's not caused by empty table, at least not only: case1: table anime_comments and actor_quotes are empty, but it work without error(http://i.imgur.com/CvKry0O.png). case2: Almost the same as case1, it turns out error but normal page as expected.

Comment: @kxxoling ok but for throwing that error (NoneType has no attribute) the only explanation is the `anime` object being `None`. And it happens when no records are found by the query. For whatever reason. :)

Comment: Yes, this is the strangest place, cause the page is always rendered successfully, so the anime object can be empty. I guess these lines maybe performed twice, the first time everything is alright, and the second time everything is empty.